# How to speed up video but leave audio normal in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I need to finish a video which I slowed down by two times with this code:

```
ffmpeg -i c:\Users\cp\Downloads\CONVERTED\tt92b.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest tt92b1.mp4
```

It works, but the problem is that the video still has 36s length instead of 18. It stops after 18s and the audio plays until end. How to cut the audio when video is finished in that code?

**EDIT**: I found some kind of  workaround adding `-t 18` parameters. But it raise an error or warning:

```
[hevc @ 000000000052f800] Could not find ref with POC 23.99 bitrate= 815.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=352 speed=0.453x
```

Anyway, it produces video as I wanted, but that time of 18 was really a guess. It could be wrong by some frames, as I couldn't find video duration variable.

Comment: Try adding this instead of just `-t 18`: `-ss 00:00 -t 00:18`. That `-ss` is the start seek and the `-t` is the duration. Perhaps the issue is you not explicitly setting a start point? HEVC video can be sensitive in that way.

Comment: I don't see difference between adding `-ss` or not. Works the same. However, some files cut this way fail to concat with each others, but sometimes it works. There are no indicators in attributes, only DTS warnings. Still, adding `-t` forces using parameter which should be solved automatically.